# IDA EBP variable offset

Tags: disassembly, assembly, static-analysis, callstack, ida

Let's take a look of how IDA displays address of local variable. For instance:

```
MOV EAX, [EBP + var_4]
```

As we all know as far as local variables go, they are located at lower addresses of EBP.

[image: Stack Frame]

Though, I have been taking it for granted and inevitable, I am still very curious. Why does IDA display local variable offset as **`[EBP + var]`**, not **`[EBP - var]`**?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have a look at the `var_4` definition at the start of the function:

```
var_4 = dword ptr -4
```

So it's actually negative as expected.

For a more complete picture, use <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> or double-click/Enter on the stack var to see the [stack frame layout](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/488.shtml):

```
-00000018 ; Two special fields " r" and " s" represent return address and saved registers.
-00000018 ; Frame size: 18; Saved regs: 4; Purge: 0
-00000018 ;
-00000018
-00000018 var_18          dd ?
-00000014 var_14          dd ?
-00000010 var_10          db 12 dup(?)
-00000004 var_4           dd ?
+00000000  s              db 4 dup(?)
+00000004  r              db 4 dup(?)
+00000008 arg_0           dd ?
+0000000C
+0000000C ; end of stack variables
```